# Flink SQL: Calculate number of new users in real time using login data

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink-SQL 1.13. The target is to calculate number of new users in real-time.

Due to some constraints, I cannot directly use register events because the accounts created there like a platform pass. One account can login into multiple games and for each game, the user is `new` when it firstly enter that game. So I can only calculate this by checking whether this account has logined to this game before from the login log. The format of login log is like:

```
user_id  game_id  login_time
111        game1    2021-05-13 01:01:01
111        game3    2021-05-23 02:02:02
```

The question is the amount of login log increases significantly every day. Although I can save the log into `HBase`, one day it will still be too large...

Is there any other way to do this? Maybe I can put historical users into redis hyperloglog, but it seems Flink-SQL does not have a redis connector yet...Thanks for your help in advance...

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO first_login_stream (user_id, first_login_time)
SELECT
  user_id,
  FIRST_VALUE(login_time) first_login_time
FROM login_log
GROUP BY user_id
```

Which goes back into your event system / kafka. Which you can read back in windows for some hourly stats (which you can save in HBase):

```
INSERT INTO hbase_stats
SELECT 
  window_start, 
  window_end, 
  count(user_id) user_count
FROM TABLE(
  TUMBLE(
    TABLE first_login_stream, 
    DESCRIPTOR(<kafka_ingestion_time>), 
    INTERVAL '1' HOUR
  )
)
GROUP BY 
  window_start,
  window_end
```

It has to be checkpointed/saved (otherwise you'll incur the full log processing on restart). The state size will only grow by the number or users and not logins (I think. You should validate that.).